# How to assign arguments for tcl script from vsim command in command line?

Tags: tcl, modelsim

I have the following tcl script:

```
vsim -voptargs="+acc" +UVM_TESTNAME=axi_test +RANDOM_TYPE=$1 +FIXED_DLY=$2 +PATH=$3 test_tb_top +UVM_MAX_QUIT_COUNT=1 
log -r test_tb_top/*
do do/default_axi_wave.do
```

I called this script from the command line by:

```
vsim -c -do test_sim.tcl random 0 params
```

I got the following error

```
Error: (vsim-3170) Could not find 'C:/ver/work.random'.
```

Comment: Hard to read your question. Please add some formatting so we can differentiate the code from the text: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: So… does `C:\ver\work.random` exist as a file?

Comment: @Donal Fellows- no. I just want to assign this value to $1.